# cutting an images at the boundary of gray colour using opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to cut an image based on the boundary of a color

As here I have an image, I would like to grab the part of the image that under the gray color i.e. just the T-shirt in this case 
 [image]

I would like also to neglect the hair on the top.

what I have done

I have tried the upper and lower boundary to get the mask

```
def maskGen (lower, upper,frame):



#frame = cv2.imread('queries\\cristiano_ronaldo.png',1)
#frame = resize(frame, width = 400)
converted = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
Mask = cv2.inRange(converted, lower, upper)

# apply a series of erosions and dilations to the mask
# using an elliptical kernel
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11, 11))
Mask = cv2.erode(Mask, kernel, iterations = 1)
Mask = cv2.dilate(Mask, kernel, iterations = 2)



# blur the mask to help remove noise, then apply the
# mask to the frame
Mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(Mask, (3, 3), 0)

return Mask
```

calling the function using the boundaries from

```
lower = np.array([240,240,220], dtype = "uint8")

upper = np.array([247,243,242], dtype = "uint8")
```

but getting a black image.

Comment: What research have you done? If any, mention it in the question

Comment: sure , will edit it and add the steps i have done for other also

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh , edited the post.
what I would like to understand here the best way to get a color cutting edge